# Scan and Compare Two Rows

Tags: vba, excel

Currently have an Excel document with a Module connected to a button.

Excel document resembles the below:

```
ROW  |  COLUMN C   |  COLUMN K
1       808           253
2       808           256
3       908           355
4       908           355
5       908           356
6       907           253
7       907           253
```

When I click on the button the following Module kicks off:

```
Sub scan()
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim dataRange2 As Range
    Dim oneCell As Range
    Dim oneCell2 As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resource Info").Range("C:C")
        Set dataRange = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resource Info").Range("K:K")
        Set dataRange2 = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each oneCell In dataRange
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataRange, oneCell) > 1 Then
            For Each oneCell2 In dataRange2
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataRange, oneCell) > 1 And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataRange2, oneCell2) <> 1 Then
                    With oneCell
                        .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    End With
                End If
            Next oneCell2
        End If
    Next oneCell
End Sub
```

I'm trying to have only Row 1,2,3,4,5 get highlighted since the Column C match but Column K data does not match from the Column C grouping.

The current Module I have highlights all rows no matter what is contained in Column K.

Comment: (Quick note, you also need to add the `.` before the use of `Range()` in your `With` statements)

Comment: Could you elaborate the criteria of grouping?  Also instead of macro, chances are you can make use of [conditional formatting](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html) or [sumproduct](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function)

Comment: Grouping should happen on Column C. In that group (i.e. matching numbers), if Column K contains two different values then rows from that group should be highlighted. Hope that's better explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your multiple `Application.CountIf` functions with a single `Appl;ication.CountIfs`.

```
Sub scan()
    Dim rw As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resource Info")
        .UsedRange.offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            If CBool(Application.CountIfs(.Columns("C"), .Cells(rw, "C").Value2, .Columns("K"), "<>" & .Cells(rw, "K"))) Then
                .Rows(rw).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jeeped - although when I ran the above code all of the header colours disappeared and no rows got highlighted.

Comment: Try it again with your sample data (I did and it worked well). If you succeed then you need to determine what is the difference between your data and the sample data you provided. You never mentioned a colored header row. I've offset the above code to leave the top row alone when resetting the highlight.

Comment: You're correct. It works like a charm. Appreciate your expertise. I'm now off to learn about the difference between CountIf and CountIfs. Thanks again!